# Batch: Return the matching lines from pipe's output to the console with regex

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, regex, findstr

I have the following domain checking bash script in Linux:

```
#!/bin/bash

TLD='.com'

while read -r domain; do
  whois -H $domain$TLD | grep -oPaq '^.*(Creation Date|record created).*$'
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $domain$TLD | tee --append 'files/registered.txt'
  else
    echo $domain$TLD | tee --append 'files/available.txt'
  fi
done < 'files/domains.txt'
```

I try to rewrite this to windows:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET "TLD=.com"

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in (%cd%\files\domains-win.txt) do (
  whoiscl -r -n %%i%TLD% | FINDSTR /R /I "\^.*Registrant Name.*$" 2>&1
)
```

I need help in regex. I just want to match the only line that contains `Registrant Name`, but now it's returning every line that containing both `Registrant` and `Name` words.

Comment: `FINDSTR /I /C:"Registrant Name"` [Use string as a literal search string (may include spaces)](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FINDSTR /I /C:"Registrant Name"
```

Applied next paragraph from [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) artice:

> *Searching for Spaces*
>
> When the search string contains multiple words, separated with spaces,
>   then `FINDSTR` will return lines that contain either word (**OR**). 
>   
> A literal search (`/C:"string"`) will reverse this behaviour and
>   allow searching for a phrase or sentence. A literal search also allow
>   searching for punctuation characters.

Read next Dave Benham's comprehensive article as well: [List of undocumented features and limitations of FINDSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/3439404).